# Show Data from .txt on DataGrid

Tags: c#

So, im trying to get all the data from my to-do.txt file and show it on the DataGrid, but when i click the grid button i get the same amount of lines i have on the .txt but the records are the same as the final one saved. This is my code:

```
    private void botaoGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tarefa dadosTarefa = new Tarefa();
        StreamReader leitor;
        string caminho = "C:\\Users\\bsoft\\Desktop\\todolist.txt";
        leitor = File.OpenText(caminho);
        string[] separador = { "|" };
        int count = 3;
        string linha = leitor.ReadLine();
        listaTarefas.Clear();

        do{             
            string[] linhaSeparada = linha.Split(separador, count, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            dadosTarefa.ToDo = linhaSeparada[0];
            dadosTarefa.Tipo = linhaSeparada[1];
            dadosTarefa.Data = linhaSeparada[2];
            listaTarefas.Add(dadosTarefa);            
            linha = leitor.ReadLine();      
        }while(linha != null);

        leitor.Close();
        atualizaGrid();
    }

    public void atualizaGrid()
    {
        dataGridTarefas.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGridTarefas.ItemsSource = listaTarefas;
    }
```

Comment: What is listaTarefas? Is it something like a ```List<Tarefa>```? If yes, then the while loop and the code you have shown seems to be okay. Did you check the values of the listaTarefas after the while loop ends? If should show all lines in your file. Maybe you need to show the code which displays your data grid

Comment: Exactly!  So, this code above is the code that my system executes when I click the "GRID" button... I´ll try to check the values after the loop, i need to show all the different lines in the .txt, but it copies the last one X amount of times. (X = number of line on .txt).

Comment: In your do loop you need to create a new object for each iteration: dadosTarefa = new Tarefa();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your do loop you are changing the value of dadosTarefa each iteration (it always has the reference to the same object. You need to declare a new dadosTarefa for each iteration as below.

```
 do{             
       string[] linhaSeparada = linha.Split(separador, count, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       dadosTarefa = new Tarefa(); //add this line
       dadosTarefa.ToDo = linhaSeparada[0];
       dadosTarefa.Tipo = linhaSeparada[1];
       dadosTarefa.Data = linhaSeparada[2];
       listaTarefas.Add(dadosTarefa);            
       linha = leitor.ReadLine();      
     }while(linha != null);
```